# How to avoid rebuilding existing wheels when using pip?

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

With `pip 1.5.X`, we can use `pip wheel` to build and cache a wheel of a package, then use `--use-wheel` with `pip install` to install from the cached wheel.

I'm trying to use this feature in a environment setup script.
This is what I'm trying:

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=/tmp Cython==0.19.2
pip install Cython==0.19.2 --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=/tmp
```

I'm expecting `pip wheel` to check if the wheel already exists before building it. But it seems to ignore the existing wheel and build every single time.

Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/855   have a look.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been using the option

```
    --find-links=/tmp
```

where /tmp is the wheelhouse. This seems to actually check the wheelhouse and not re-download things. Using your example, try this:

```
    pip wheel --find-links=/tmp --wheel-dir=/tmp Cython==0.19.2
```